# Hide list of logged in users on lock screen when using Remove Desktop Connection Broker

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2016

We have two remote desktop servers (for redundancy reasons) and connection
broker handling the connections for them, using Windows 2016.

On the Windows lock screen there's a list of other logged in users on the bottom left corner of the screen. Is it possible to hide the list of users and if yes, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These group policy (GPO) entries should help you, I've also got some registry spots in there, but GPO is much preferred usually.

- Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options\ **[Interactive logon: Display user information when the session is locked](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/interactive-logon-display-user-information-when-the-session-is-locked)**

  - Registry location: *HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System, value=DontDisplayLockedUserId*
- Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options\ **[Interactive logon: Don't display last signed-in](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/interactive-logon-do-not-display-last-user-name)**
- Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options\ **[Interactive logon: Don't display username at sign-in](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/interactive-logon-dont-display-username-at-sign-in)**

  - Registry location: *HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\DontDisplayLastUserName*